# What is the density of $(X,X)$

Tags: probability

It might be stupid question, but:

Let $X$ be a RV with density $f(x)$. What is the "joint" density of random vector $(X,X)$?

Comment: This is only one random variable, do you mean the vector $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Comment: i mean vector (X,Y), where X=Y (X is exactly the same function on sample space as Y)

Comment: When you say  $(X, X)$, that is not the same as throwing a die twice. It's the same as throwing a die once, then write down the result two times.

Comment: I think this could be a nice question with a bit more context. How did you encounter this question?

Answer (score 2):

So you know that $P(X\leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy$, and you want to find $P(X\leq x_1,X\leq x_2)$.

But this probability is certainly dictated by whichever of $x_1$ and $x_2$ is the smallest, so

$$P(X\leq x_1,X\leq x_2) = P(X\leq \min(x_1,x_2))=\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x_1,x_2)}f(y)dy.$$

So you see that $(X,X)$ is a *degenerate* random vector in the sense that its distribution is not two-dimensional. This also means that there is no joint density of $(X,X)$ in the usual sense. The above gives you a rule for finding the distribution of $(X,X)$ by using the single density of the random variable $X$.